# IE11 - Balise object pdf over all elements

Tags: css-position, internet-explorer-11, preview, object-tag

On IE11, when there is a modal opened or a fixed element, the PDF's preview on  just passed over all the content.
I tried to z-index etc but nothing seems to work, it works well on all other browsers.
Is there a solution only in CSS/HTML ?

Here's a [example](https://husk.fr/iebug/) (only bugs on IE)

Answer (score 0):

I try to check your sample code and find that you are using **object** tag to display the PDF which is not working in IE 11.

I suggest you to try to use **Iframe** to display the PDF in IE 11.

You can replace the **object** tag with code below may help you to solve your issue.

```html
<div id="pdf">
   <iframe src="https://www.vousnousils.fr/casden/pdf/id00264.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I've already tried to use iframe tag, but the matter is the fallback isn't working if there is no Adobe installed, there is no error message to.